# How to check exist array in part of string in Smarty?

Tags: php, arrays, smarty, strpos

I have a variable that includes the name of products called `$product->name` and I defined an array that includes brand names. I want to if exist brand name in `$product->name` show brand name to user. I can wrote this codes in PHP but my website is tpl and I have to wrote it to Smarty. my PHP codes is below:

```
$brands = array('ASUS','HP','Lenovo');
foreach($brands as $brand){
if (strpos($product.name, $brand) !== false) 
    echo $brand;
}
```

How I can convert this code to smarty?

Answer (score 0):

I didn’t test it but you could try.

```
{* smarty *}
{if strpos($product.name, 'ASUS') != false} 
    {* you code *}
{/if}
```

In smarty :

> All PHP conditionals and functions are recognized, such as ||, or, &&,
>   and, is_array(), etc.

also, if you can, you should consider doing this in your controller, that way you could do it with mysql or php.